# Descobrir se smartphone (Android e iOS) está com Fuso Horário Automático habilitado usando ngCordova

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova

Um app Ionic v1 precisa saber se o smartphone (Android e iOS) está com Fuso Horário Automático habilitado, imagino que isso seja feito usando ngCordova, como posso fazer isso?

Para algumas ações no app, preciso garantir que o usuário esteja com Fuso Horário Automático habilitado, para que não envie dados com data/hora falsos, se não estiver ele não poderá prosseguir.

Comment: Após a sua edição entendi mais a sua necessidade, então adicionei algumas coisas a mais na resposta, com um exemplo "teórico", só para entender a ideia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu criei um [plugin para ngCordova](https://github.com/edsonhoraciojunior/verify-automatic-date-time-zone) para resolver isso, atualmente só suporta Android, pois o iOS não disponibiliza programaticamente as configurações de data e hora do iPhone.

#### Como usar

```
window.VerifyAutomaticDateTimeZone.isAutomaticChecked(function(isIt){
  if (isIt == 'true') {
        // fazer algo
    } else {
        // fazer outra coisa
    }
});
```

Caso `window.VerifyAutomaticDateTimeZone` seja undefined, englobe a chamada em `$ionicPlatform.ready` ou `ionic.Platform.ready`

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
    // codigo aqui...
});
```

Comment: Com perdão, acho muito legal a iniciativa, mas o fuso horário automatico estar ativado não garante estar correto. Mas vale pelo incentivo, talvez no futuro você possa implementar algo com os proprios serviços que o Android usa para "baixar" o horário da timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que descobrir se esta habilitado não será possível (não tenho certeza, talvez exista algum plugin compilado que resolva, até o momento não achei nada), mas pode tentar comparar o valor da "API `Date` nativa do JavaScript:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

E criar uma página com resposta HTTP em um formato qualquer, por exemplo JSON, que retorne a hora do teu servidor, estando esta página configurada com o timezone desejado.

Por exemplo para pegar a timezone do celular seria isto:

```js
let tz = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

console.log(tz);
```

Ou pegar a hora atual e comparar com de algum serviço de API (proprio ou de terceiros):

```js
console.log(new Date().toString());
```

E com uma requisição HTTP usando [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) poderia obter os dados do servidor e compara-los, o que vai exigir algum desenvolvimento no back-end, no entanto como alternativa existem serviços de terceiros que retornam este tipo de dados, como o proprio do google maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

Então poderia mandar a requisição no `$http` para:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=<LATITUDE>,<LONGITUDE>&timestamp=<TEMPO ATUAL EM SEGUNDOS>&key=<SUA CHAVE DA CONTA DE DESENVOLVEDOR GOOGLE>
```

Vai ter que usar algo para pegar a localização atual do usuário, então troque:

- `<LATITUDE>` pela longitude pega
- `<LONGITUDE>` pela longitude pega
- `<TEMPO ATUAL EM SEGUNDOS>` por `Date.now()`
- `<SUA CHAVE DA CONTA DE DESENVOLVEDOR GOOGLE>` sua chave de desenvolvedor, tem que ter conta de desenvolvedor para usar os serviços do Google Maps.

Outra solução possível seria usar o serviço https://timezonedb.com/api (existem outros do mesmo tipo), no caso usuaria esta função: https://timezonedb.com/references/get-time-zone

---

> Para algumas ações no app, preciso garantir que o usuário esteja com Fuso Horário Automático habilitado, para que não envie dados com data/hora falsos, se não estiver ele não poderá prosseguir.

Neste caso simplesmente envie o horário da requisição junto ao payload, algo mais ou menos como:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://foo.bar/api/foo/bar',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        'foo': $scope.foo,
        'bar': $scope.bar,
        'time': new Date().toUTCString()
    }
}).then(function (response) {
   console.log("sucesso", response);
}, function (response) {
   console.log("falhou", response);
});
```

Claro que leve em consideração que o Brasil tem diferentes zonas horárias, então seria interessante enviar em UTC para fazer a partir disto a checagem no back-end, então no teu servidor HTTP, aonde irá se comunicar com o seu serviço, cheque o parâmetro `time` do payload, no seu caso creio que seja PHP, então faria isto:

```
strtotime($_POST['time']);
```

Então você terá o valor em segundos, o que poderá usar o `gmdate` (acho que seria isto, não testei ainda) e comparar com os valores do servidor, somente do ano, mês e hora. Minutos talvez seja irrelevante e possa ser algo não muito preciso.

Não criei nada, mas é apenas a ideia para você mesmo implementar.

Comment: Sobre sua última edição de passar `time` na requisição, e se o usuário alterar o fuso horário e data manualmente para enviar informação falsa?

Comment: Eu não quero que ele possa enviar qualquer fuso horário, mas quero o fuso horário "verdadeiro", que seria o fuso horário da rede de celular que ele está conectado.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior mas se ele alterar e enviar a informação com outro horário você vai usar o TIME= do lado do servidor para comparar com o payload, se forem diferentes é porque o celular não esta sincronizado com a hora correta, entende?

Comment: o app tem usuários de países diferentes, com timezones diferentes, então não posso usar o time do servidor como base, certo?

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior ai o cenário muda, um pouco né, vou tentar criar um exemplo que atenda a diferentes regiões, não vai precisar de muita coisa, mas talvez dependendo de onde comprou o celular ou da configuração dê um pouco de problema, vou fazer alguns testes para ter certeza que o código tanto JS quanto PHP funcionem o melhor possivel, não vai ser rápido produzir um exemplo assim, mas prometo tentar ser o mais breve, se tiver um pouco de paciencia :)

Comment: acho que não precisa criar, eu já estou criando um Plugin Cordova que irá verificar essas configurações nativamente no Android e iOS, aí postarei a resposta aqui.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior isso vai depender de exemplos também, se achar faço-o primeiro que a sugestão da checagem com servidor, mas quero que entenda que mesmo a sincronização sendo automatica não garante de estar sincronizado, fora que uma coisa deve entender sobre o stackoverflow, postamos respostas para ajudar a quem pergunta e a futuros visitantes que chegarem na sua pergunta, então a ideia é tornar util de diferentes formas, e sobre códigos e plataformas, é sempre legal deixar uma alternativa, nem sempre o que você acredita ser o melhor é o melhor de verdade.